# AngularJS HTML5 video ng-src empty from directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

My application loads several objects from a REST service. Each object contains a property that represents the Uri of a video file. My application takes this as the source to display several videos to the user.

Because I need to catch when a user plays a video (event), I load the HTML5 video markup using an Angular directive:

```
app.directive("aVideo", function($http){
return {        
    template: '<video class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" ng-src="[[[creativeViewModel.post.addTrustedUri()]]]" controls preload="metadata"</video>',
    scope:{
        creative: "=",
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {         
        $(element).find("video").on("play", function () {
            $http.post('/post/' + scope.creative.post.doc_id + '/views?_csrf=' + csrfToken)
            .success(function(data){

            })
            .error(function(error){             

            }); 
        });                     
    },
}
```

});

Consequently, the HTML markup for the video is like this:

```
<div a-video creative="creativeViewModel"></div>
```

The function *addTrustedUri* is part of the object itself, as follows:

```
addTrustedUri: function addTrustedUri() {
            return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(this.post.media);
        },
```

However, the following is the  code that is given back to the user browser:

```
<video class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" ng-src="" controls="" preload="metadata" <="" video=""></video>
```

As you can see, the ng-src attribute shows up empty, even though I am using the $sce.trustAsResourceUrl method to enable it. Note that the domain from which the video files are being loaded is not the same as the app's domain (it's a CDN).

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Comment: I know it's been a long time since this post, but did you find a solution ?

Comment: @Bonswouar see own answer below.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in this answer, I could not find a proper solution for this problem, but instead I did come to an acceptable workaround. Here is the workaround:

```
app.directive("aVideo", function($http, $sce){
    return {
        template: '<a class="video-file"><img class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 poster-file" ng-src="[[[post.creative.media.poster]]]"></img><span class="play-button-overlay"><img src="/img/video-play-3-256.png" /></span><div class="clearer"></div></a>',       
        scope:{
            post: "=",
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).find("img").on("click", function () {
                $(element).find('img').remove();
                $(element).append('<video controls width="100%"></video>');
                var video = $(element).find('video');
                video.addClass('col-xs-12');
                video.attr('poster', $sce.trustAsUrl(scope.post.creative.media.poster));
                video.append("<source src='" + $sce.trustAsUrl(scope.post.tempUri) + "' type='" + scope.post.creative.media.contentType + "'></source>");
                video.append("<source src='" + $sce.trustAsUrl(scope.post.creative.media.webm) + "' type='video/webm'></source>");
                video[0].play();
            });
        },
    }
});
```

Basically what this does is to display the video element first as a picture. When the user clicks on the img element, the `link` property of the directive element kicks in. Here, I append a video element and forcefully add the source elements for mp4 and webm formats and then trigger the video to play by calling `video.play()` function.

Answer (score -1):

You're dynamically adding a directive (ngSrc) in your template. For angular to recognize the expression, you need to `transclude: true` as explained in the angular docs under [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-wraps-other-elements).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Adding the transclude parameter as suggested did not change the behavior. It looks to me as if angular is refusing to read url at all.